# Bios doesn't boot with 3 or 4 sticks of RAM

Tags: bios

Each stick has 8GB of ram, but bios doesn't run when I fill completely ram slots.. This is my first build.. Every slot and stick works, I tried. It only boots with 2 sticks (16GB)

Motherboard is MSI Z170A Gaming M7
Ram is F4-2133C15Q-32GRR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should boot with 1, 2 or 4 DIMMs installed. Check that your BIOS version is 1.7, and if not install the current BIOS update.

#### Links

- [Download page](http://www.msi.com/support/mb/Z170A-GAMING-M7.html#support_download)
- [Instructions](http://www.msi.com/files/pdf/How_to_flash_the_BIOS.doc) as Word document
- [Video instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRyFMf0D9Lc)